# Warning: Failed propType: Required prop `children` was not specified in `Pane`. Check the render method of `first-time-tab`

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, reactjs, redux

- I am new to js.
- I have a tabs code which works fine.
- I tried to integrate my code into the codebase but I am getting a warning...providing it in fiddle both code and warning.
- can you guys tell me how to fix it.

  render: function() {
          return (

  ```
        < Pane label = "Account Setup"
        subtitle = "Days 1 and 2"
        liClass = "sports-setup-ico first-time-active ft-active-tab"
        content = {
          this.state.panes[0]
        } >

        < /Pane>

        < Pane label = "Investments Purchase"
        subtitle = "Approx. Day 3"
        liClass = "sports-invest-ico"
        content = {
          this.state.panes[1]
        } >

        < /Pane>

        < Pane label = "Balance and Portfolio"
        subtitle = "Approx. Day 4"
        liClass = "sports-balance-ico"
        content = {
          this.state.panes[2]
        } >

        < /Pane>

        < Pane label = "IPerformance"
        subtitle = "Approx. Day 5"
        liClass = "sports-perf-ico"
        content = {
          this.state.panes[3]
        } >

        < /Pane> < /Tabs>
      );
    }
  });
  ```

Answer (score 1):

In "not working fiddle" you have:

```
var Pane = React.createClass({
      displayName: 'Pane',
      propTypes: {
        label: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired,
        children: React.PropTypes.element.isRequired
      },
      render: function() {
        return ( < div > {
          this.props.children
        } < /div>);
      }
    });
```

And yet still try to pass content instead. Change the prop from `children` to `content` in render method or in Pane class.

Comment: From the error message : Failed propType: **Required prop `children`was not specified in `Pane`**. Check the render (..) So I checked if there was such required prop in Pane class, and - after that - was it passed correctly. It wasn't passed at all - instead you were passing content prop, which was the prop of Pane class in working fiddle. Simple mix up :)